# How to use Python library in android application code

Tags: android, python

I have `Python` script which has `numpy` and PIL `Python` packages installed in `virtualenv`. But the package which I have installed I want to use in `android` code. Also want to execute script using button activity.

I have used `Jython` but seems not working at my end.

Is anyone have an idea that how can I used `Python` packages within `android` code?

Comment: Take a look at Kivy?

Comment: I have tried kivy.but seems other PIP install packages not working within Android code such as Numpy,PIL.Do you know how to use those packages inside android application code.